# Why my element is not getting add at start index when i call addfirst method in linkedlist

Tags: java

This is my linked list code:

```java
package com.dishank.primitive;

public class LL {
    Node head;
    
    class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        
        Node(int data){
            this.data=data;
            this.next=null;
        }
    }

    // add first
    public void addfirst(int data) {
        Node newnode = new Node(data);
        if(head==null) {
            head=newnode;
            return; 
        }
        newnode.next=head;
        head=newnode;
    }

    //add last
    public void addlast(int data) {
        Node newnode=new Node(data);
        if(head==null) {
            head=newnode;
            return; 
        }
        Node currNode = head;
        while(currNode.next!=null) {
            currNode=currNode.next;
        }
        currNode.next=newnode;
    }

    public void printt() {
        Node currNode = head;
        while(currNode!=null) {
            System.out.print(currNode.data+" -> ");
            currNode=currNode.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LL list = new LL();
        list.addfirst(6);
        list.addfirst(9);
        list.printt();
    }

}
```

Expected op is 6 -> 9, but I'm getting 9 -> 6 ->. I tried updating my code, but nothing works. What is the problem?

Comment: Why is your expected result 6 -> 9? You also use `addfirst` for 9, meaning it will be added *before* 6, because it was called after adding 6.

Comment: ... you must `addLast(9)` if you want it added as *Last*

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score -2):

the answer is true,you define code addfirst,is mean per newnode will add  to the head position. you add 6, head ->6 ,again add 9，9.next = head，head - >9,when you print ,is just 9 -> 6, if you want 6 —>9 ,you should to use addlast